# How to scroll two UITableViews symmetrically?

Tags: ios, uitableview

In my app I have two table views. Both are same height and width and same cell count.
I want when tableview A Scroll Simultaneously tableview B also scroll.

[image]

Comment: What did you try? I guess stackoverflow is not a code writing service so you should ask specific questions and not "AnyOne Send Code"

Comment: @boobesh You should at least write code of what you have tried. This will help you and let us help you better.

Comment: try using `collectionview` instead of using two `tableview`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use scrollview delegate scrollViewDidScroll for this purpose. This will do the exact thing you want.

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    if scrollView == self.tableA{
        self.tableB.setContentOffset(self.tableA.contentOffset, animated: false)
    }
    else if scrollView == self.tableB{
        self.tableA.setContentOffset(self.tableA.contentOffset, animated: false)
    }
    print("scrollViewDidScroll") // to check whether this function is called while scrolling 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**TRY THIS:**

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView 
{
  <your tableView Name>.contentOffset = scrollview.contentOffset
}
```

As Tableview inherits from ScrollView. Try this.

FOR SWIFT 4:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) 

{
   <your tableView Name>.contentOffset = scrollview.contentOffset
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using tableview you can use UIPickerView with two components.
If you need code let me know.